# Typescript derived class constructor returns base class instance

Tags: typescript

One would expect something basic like inheritance to work in Typescript, but apparently not! I have code something like this:

```
class GrowableBuffer extends Buffer {

  constructor(size: number) {
    super(size);
  }

  public append(b: Buffer): GrowableBuffer {
    ...
```

[`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) is a node type.

In another class I have a property

```
  private buffer: GrowableBuffer = new GrowableBuffer(0);
```

However `buffer` ends up being just a `Buffer`, not a `GrowableBuffer` so `this.buffer.append()` complains that `append()` does not exist. Wtf? I don't get any Typescript errors during compilation, and it appears to produce vaguely sane results in the Typescript playground, but my output code is this monstrosity:

```
var GrowableBuffer = /*#__PURE__*/
function(_Buffer) {
    Object(_Why_is_my_home_directory_here_node_modules_babel_runtime_corejs2_helpers_esm_inherits__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__["default"])(GrowableBuffer, _Buffer);

    function GrowableBuffer(size) {
        var _this;

        Object(_Why_is_my_home_directory_here_node_modules_babel_runtime_corejs2_helpers_esm_classCallCheck__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__["default"])(this, GrowableBuffer);

        _this = Object(_Why_is_my_home_directory_here_node_modules_babel_runtime_corejs2_helpers_esm_possibleConstructorReturn__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__["default"])(this, Object(_Why_is_my_home_directory_here_modules_babel_runtime_corejs2_helpers_esm_getPrototypeOf__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__["default"])(GrowableBuffer).call(this, size));
        return _this;
    }
```

Is this supposed to work, and is Webpack messing it up?

Comment: Do you have the typings for Buffer installed?

Comment: How do I tell? It's a Node type so I assume so?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node

Comment: It's not explicitly listed in my `dependencies` or `devDependencies` but it is in `package-lock.json` so I assume it is installed by default somehow.

Comment: Or possibly because I'm using Electron and that depends on it.

Comment: I tried adding it explicitly anyway and it made no difference.

Comment: Is it possible that your `buffer` property has the same name as an inherited property? The `Buffer` class has one of that name ([docs link](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_buffer)), perhaps your other class is getting its `buffer` property overwritten by a superclass constructor? You need to make your question into a [mcve], anyway, otherwise we can only speculate.